# is there any different behaviour between single var assignment and multiple var assignment in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a function which will print Fibonacci series

```
def fib(n):
    """ print the fibonacci series up to n."""
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
      print(a)
      a, b = b, a + b
```

which works just fine. but when i change some coding style it does not work as i intended. so what is happening here ?

```
def fib(n):
    """ print the fibonacci series up to n."""
    a = 0
    b = 1
    while a < n:
       print(a)
       a = b
       b = a + b
```

above code does not print same result as first code but i can see same code in both function. i m beginner in python.

Comment: Well your indentations are off in the second case.

Comment: Yes it’s different. In the second you assign `a` before doing the addition. It’s the same as setting `b` to `b+b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is different behavior. Everything on the right side of the `=` gets evaluated *before any of it gets assigned* to the left side of the `=`. Multiple assignment just means that you compute a tuple on the right side, and assign it to a tuple on the left side.

```
a, b = b, a+b
# computes (b, a+b)
# matches with (a, b)
# assigns the computed values to a and b respectively
```

versus

```
a = b
# assigns the value of b to a
b = a + b
# computes a + b (since a was just set equal to b, this is the same as b + b)
# assigns that computed value to b
```

---

If you need to have all your assignments on separate lines, then you'll either need a temporary holding variable for swapping `a` and `b`:

```
temp = a
a = b
b = b + temp
```

or do something fancy to preserve the difference between `b` and `a`:

```
b = b + a
a = b - a
```

Multiple assignment is the "most correct" solution to the problem, mainly because it's the most concise.

Comment: man i did not seen this much explanation in their documentation. thanks for elaboration

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have not correctly swap the values in the second method

**Straight forward solution is:**

```
def fib(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    while a < n:
        print(a)
        c = a + b   # c is the temporary variable
        a = b
        b = c
```

In first method, addition gets evaluated first then **a becomes b and b becomes the added value**. Whereas in the second method you store added value in some other variable then you do swap the value as shown above code.